# cudart32_31_9.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have a visual studio 2010 c++ solution (with cuda and nsight), it builds just fine, but I try to run it, it tells me this:

```
The program can't start because cudart32_31_9.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I've looked and I have cudart32_31_9.dll and cudart.lib on my computer and in my linker options, I've set the Additional Dependencies with the link to my cudart.lib (which is suppose to be "linked" with the dll in question).

I've looked a on Google, but the only things I found seems to be related to a program called "Folding"... which isn't quite my problem.

Any hint would be appeciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming it's a "typo", but there is no point in linking against a DLL. To solve your main problem however, make sure that cudart32_31_9.dll is either in the directory of your executable, or that its directory is part of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: i have the same issue, but the thing is the folder is part of the path environment variable and it's still not working...

Comment: @RobertIagar Once you added the path to the environment variable, did you restart whatever you launch your application from? That is, the IDE, the command prompt, or whatever? If so, perhaps download Dependency Walker and drag your application into there. Then profile it to see if it finds all the required DLLs or not. And are you sure you have the exact version that is mentioned in the error message?

Comment: The thing is you have run any application that references it as administrator, otherwise it won't look in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @RobertIagar Hmm, I'd have to confirm if that is the case. I don't think that's the situation on my machines. Though perhaps I ended up adding it to the per-user PATH... When I confirm I'll let you know.